# How can I manage locks and row/column visibility in office js api

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

We want to integrate excel online to one of our application. Our application needs to handle the user by locking/unlocking cells and change rows/columns visibility programmatically.

I found how to create an add-in that can create worksheet, insert data and much more...

example at :

- https://officesnippetexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#/snippets/excel,
- https://github.com/OfficeDev

But i could not find any way to change the lock and visibility. The feature might not be available yet, or i just couldn't find the documentation for it. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just released the 1.2 set of APIs to the public, which allow you to change visibility of a Range to hide/show columns/rows.
You can find an overview of the new APIs here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_1.2_OpenSpec/excel

For hiding/showing rows and columns the property is Range.rowHidden and Range.ColumnHidden, both Boolean.

Furthermore, we also now have protection to lock a cell. This is on Range.Format.Protection.

Comment: @Kadgiko you can read and write to the rowHidden/columnHidden property, e.g. `range.rowHidden = true` will hide the rows of the range, or you can load the property and then the Boolean state will tell you if the rows of the range are visible or not.

Right now the new 1.2 functionalities are only available via Office365 builds, so if you are installing Office via Office365 then please update your client, if you have installed office via a traditional purchased license then you'll have to wait until those bits are updated at this point in time.

Comment: Thanks it is exactly what i needed. However, I found out that when I hide column, excel repaint has some trouble. I still need to try it on excel online but i was wondering if there was a manual repaint that can be done from office.js api

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer on my previous comment, I deleted it because I did an error, and realized it right after posting. I am currently using Excel 2016 and VS2015 Project for Office so it should be perfect.

Comment: I tried the same thing in Napa Office App to try in Excel Online and it seem to work better for the repaint problem.

Comment: @PhilipRueker is there a way to get a range by row, column, numRows, numColumns? I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848153/javascript-api-for-office-getrange-method