# JavaScript API for Office getRange method

Tags: javascript, excel, javascript-api-for-office

Is there a way to get a range by `row`, `column`, `numRows`, `numColumns`?

For example:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 3, 4).load("values");
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next release of ExcelAPI 1.7 we will have `worksheet.getRangeByIndexes` which is exactly what you are looking for.

In the meantime you can achieve the same by doing the following:

```
var range = sheet.getCell(1,2).getResizedRange(3,4);
```

-Philip, Software Engineer on the Office Extensibility team

Comment: Thank you, Philip, that's exactly what I need! When will be the Excel API 1.7 released?

Comment: @Valip We don't have a clear release date for 1.7 yet, but we will have it out in Beta by next month most likely.